# Efficient way to find a date in a gsheet column (date column sorted - all days of a year)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wonder if there is an efficient, built in way to find a date in a gsheet column  and return the row number?

This is what I got so far. It works. However, do I really have to iterate through all cells?

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(1,sh.getLastColumn()).activate();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
  for(var n=0;n<data.length;n++){
    var date = new Date(data[n][0]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if(date==today){
      Logger.log("FOUND n: " + n);
      break;
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If with 'built-in' you refer to a formula, I guess you could try

```
=filter(row(A2:A), A2:A=today())
```

(Change range to suit).